# If object passes y value then call function

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have an object that is moving down progressively and I want the touch function to be called whenever the object passes a certain Y.

So I have a if condition that checks if square.y is bigger than 150. If that condition is true, I want to be able to call a touch function.

How can i do that?

I have tried doing this, but it's not working.

```
 if (square.y > 150)  then
    function square:touch (event) 
            // do something
    end
 end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined the function `square:touch`, but you didn't call it. You need to call it using `square:touch()`:

```
if square.y > 150  then
    function square:touch (event) 
       print("calling touch")
    end
    square:touch()
end
```

You can also define the function outside the `if` statement if you want, to make it more clear:

```
function square:touch (event) 
   print("calling touch")
end

if square.y > 150  then
    square:touch()
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This was very helpful. If i do this and somehow I drag the square to a place where y is lower than 150, the square will freeze right? Is that a good thing to happen? How can I change that?

Comment: @Glund I'm not able to help you with that because I've never used Corona.

Comment: Fair enough. Thank you